# Verification: How tensors work and calculating symmetric power of a representation

Tags: representation-theory, tensors

I'm taking a first course in representation theory, haven't done anything with tensors before, and am dealing with a bit of "tensor-phobia". Please can I have a verification that I am doing this correctly, as in:

- Have I gotten the correct result?
- Have I used notation and terminology correctly? If I have abused notation or terminology somewhere, what's the correct thing to write?

Consider the $2$-dimensional irreducible representation $(\rho, V)$ of $D_8 = \langle r, s : r^4 = s^2 = e, srs = r^{-1} \rangle$ defined by

$$\rho(r) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\
 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad \rho(s) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

I want to calculate the representation $S^2 \rho$. It should have basis $\{ e_1 e_1, e_1 e_2, e_2 e_2 \}$ (where $V$ has basis $\{ e_1, e_2 \}$ which the matrices are written in.)

Then, if I am not mistaken, calculating $\rho(p)e_i e_j$ and $\rho(s) e_i e_j$ for each $1 \leq i \leq j \leq 2$ we should get

$$S^2 \rho(r) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad S^2 \rho(s) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Does this all look right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results look right, I try to clarify the solution. It is true that $\mathrm{Sym}^2V$ is (complex) three-dimensional and a basis is given by $(e_1^2,e_1e_2,e_2^2)$. By your initial matrices you can deduce that
\begin{align*}
\rho(r)e_1=e_2, & \qquad \rho(r)e_2=-e_1,\\
\rho(s)e_1=e_1, & \qquad \rho(s)e_2=-e_2.
\end{align*}
By definition, any element $g$ acts on $\mathrm{Sym}^2V$ via $\rho(g)(v\odot w) = \rho(g)v \odot \rho(g)w$ (I use the $\odot$ for the symmetric tensor product). Hence
\begin{align*}\rho(r)(e_1^2) & = \rho(r)e_1\odot \rho(r)e_1=e_2 \odot e_2 = e_2^2, \\
\rho(r)(e_1e_2) & = \rho(r)e_1 \odot \rho(r)e_2 = -e_2 \odot e_1=-e_1e_2, \\
\rho(r)(e_2^2) & = \rho(r)e_2 \odot \rho(r)e_2 = e_1\odot e_1 = e_1^2.
\end{align*}
The corresponding matrix representation is then

$$\rho(r) = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right),$$
which corresponds to your result. You can verify the other one.